# How can we define complexity in the context of biology?

Tags: theoretical-biology, complexity

Can somebody provide a definition of complexity in the context of biology?

Is it something of a personal **opinion** on the side of the user to decide precisely what s/he means by using the word complexity or is there something all biologists can agree upon? Is there any "standard" for the use of the term complexity or is such standard simply unattainable in our current level of knowledge and/or understanding of the living world?

To the moderator-I want to know **What is complexity in biology?**  in GENERAL, not only in the specific example of measuring it for an individual. One can argue complexity can be used to compare and even to "cast a vote" about the superiority or inferiority of many objects of study in biology, not just individual organisms. What about the complexity of an ecosystem, of a particular organ, of the interactions of macromolecules and so on. Are they **not** legitimate instances when the term complexity can be used without inferring to its meaning? This is the purpose of my question, not to *merely* measure the complexity of an individual. This is why I don't think it's duplicate of the question you mentioned. How is my reply?

Comment: Totally subjective. Just like saying in a paper that X was *very* Y (Y being big, small, long, complex *etc*)

Comment: So, there isn't anything like some biological "standard" for complexity. Is it what you're saying?

Comment: Biology is a broad subject. You probably need to be more specific for useful answers. What subjects of biology are you interested in? In loose terms, relative complexity is often used (something is more complex than something else), but clear definitions (where there are any) are likely to be sub-field dependent.

Comment: Biology is a rabbit hole that only gets deeper. Real complexity is falling further than anyone else ever has and trying to see an end in sight. You can also construe this as insanity, but to each their own.

Comment: @RozennKeribin To me, this question seems broader, so I don't think it is a duplicate (it might be *too broad* though).

Comment: As I mentioned above, I think you need to narrow down the answer set. Otherwise the question is too broad/vague. *Complexity* is just a word, and it is used differently in different areas of biology. Therefore, there doesn't exist a single definition, and a question such as "*What is complexity in biology?*" is too broad to be covered in the SE-format.

Comment: I think complexity is not always subjective; rather it is quite similar to quantitative variables. Say a plastic-comb is more complicated than a plastic rod. Or an asymmetric irregular shape is more complicated than an ellipse and an ellipse  is more complicated than a circle. Or the arithmetic procedure (or steps) procedure to find square root of a number, is much more complicated than the arithmetic procedure (or steps) to find sum of 2 numbers. Though it is not so easy to define and formulate; different  possible values of complexity exists.

Comment: IMO this question should be moved to mathematics.se with an edit suggestion "could we define and measure complexity of a system?" (instead of only biological system). Probably there would have the expertise to measure things like "probability", "importance", "advantage" etc. that could not be measured directly with a scale or an weight box etc.

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss01D.png) is known as complexity in biology.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate, but the answer seems trivial: there isn't a single definition of complexity.

Comment: I think marking this as a duplicate is the best solution - although the question here is more broad than the question there, I think the accepted answer to that question is 100% applicable to this one, and I don't think it is possible to come up with a better answer. That answer makes clear why having a definition for complexity is important, explains how the answers you get will completely depend on that definition, and gives some examples for the OP to consider when possibly reformulating the question.

Comment: I had to once again edit the question to satisfy you. Are you going to accept it now?

Comment: Oh, come on, what would it take you to accept a good question about complexity in biology?